# Text overlaying hero image in Bootstrap 3 overflowing container

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

This seems so unbelievably silly, but I've tried everything and can't seem to get this fixed.

Using Bootstrap 3, fully updated, I am trying to overlay text on my responsive hero image that is set inside a container. Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/megkadams/62g7s/1/

The row of text is exceeding the width of the container and I can't figure out why. I have almost the exact same code on another site, except that the hero image is full-screen and lays outside of the container, and it works just fine.

Any help would be so great.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="landing-header">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <img src="../assets/img/landing-img.png" alt="Photo description" class="landing-img" />
            <div class="landing-header-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h1>Landing Page Title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="page-body">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>The rest of my body</h2>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Close row -->
</div> <!-- Close container -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text isn't actually extending past the width of its container, although it appears that way. The culrpit is the 15 pixels of padding applied to the left and right side of .col-lg-12 :

```
.col-lg-12 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

So while this padding pushes **img.landing-img** inward, it does not push **div.landing-header-content** inward because it is ***position: absolute***. Absolutely positioned elements are not affected by padding.

I've updated your fiddle to fix this, and made a few other minor adjustments that should help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/62g7s/7/

Comment: Thank you SO much. I'd tried pulling padding off or negative margining everything except that. And I really appreciate the explanation so I've got it for next time.